# Efficient datastructure to query by "in-between" key in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a database like this

```
key - value
0     10
1.2   20
2.7   25
3.5   35
...
```

I want to create a function that retrieves the associated value given a key that is continuous, e.g. for 0.2 or 0.4 should returns 10, for anything in [2.7,3.5[ should return 25, everything higher or equal to the last key should returns 35.

The original data structure is a dataframe, and I am currently using a loop over each row of it, but I wonder which other datastructure (possibly in Base) would be more efficient, especially in  querying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `key` is sorted then something like this should be efficient assuming that `df` is a `DataFrame` where you store your data:

```
df.value[searchsortedlast(df.key, value_you_want_to_find)]
```

Wrapping it in a function using a barrier can be a bit faster (but not much I guess):

```
range_find(df::AbstractDataFrame, val) =
    _range_find(df.key, df.value, val)

_range_find(key::AbstractVector, value:AbstractVector, val) =
    value[searchsortedlast(key, val)]
```

EDIT:

It should be `searchsortedlast` given your range condition.

Note that this function will throw an error if you pas `val` less than minimum of `values`, but will return a last value if you pass a `val` greater than the last value (essentially the last interval is assumed to be `[df.values[end], Inf[`. If you want a different behavior on the "borders" you have do add some additional checks manually.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.. (I was not aware of `searchsortedlast`)